# How to make matplotlib show legend which falls out of figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I draw a graph but unfortunately my legend falls out of the figure. How can I correct it?
I put a dummy code to illustrate it:
[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from bisect import bisect_left,bisect_right
import numpy as np
global ranOnce
ranOnce=False
def threeLines(x):
    """Draws a function which is a combination of two lines intersecting in
    a point one with a large slope and one with a small slope.
    """
    start=0
    mid=5
    end=20
    global ranOnce,slopes,intervals,intercepts;
    if(not ranOnce):
        slopes=np.array([5,0.2,1]);
        intervals=[start,mid,end]
        intercepts=[start,(mid-start)*slopes[0]+start,(end-mid)*slopes[1]+(mid-start)*slopes[0]+start]
        ranOnce=True;
    place=bisect_left(intervals,x)
    if place==0:
        y=(x-intervals[place])*slopes[place]+intercepts[place];
    else:    
        y=(x-intervals[place-1])*slopes[place-1]+intercepts[place-1];
    return y;
def threeLinesDrawer(minimum,maximum):
    t=np.arange(minimum,maximum,1)
    fig=plt.subplot(111)
    markerSize=400;
    fig.scatter([minimum,maximum],[threeLines(minimum),threeLines(maximum)],marker='+',s=markerSize)

    y=np.zeros(len(t));
    for i in range(len(t)):
        y[i]=int(threeLines(t[i]))
    fig.scatter(t,y)
    fig.grid(True)
    fig.set_xlabel('Y')
    fig.set_ylabel('X')
    legend1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, fc="r")
    legend2 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, fc="b")
    legend3 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, fc="g")
    fig.legend([legend1,legend2,legend3], ["p(y|x) likelihood","Max{p(y|x)} for a specific x","Y distribution"],
    bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)

threeLinesDrawer(0,20)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the space that a set of axes takes within a figure by modifying the subplot parameters. For example, add the following line just before `plt.show()`:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(top=.9, bottom=.1, hspace=.1, left=.1, right=.9, wspace=.1)
```

You should tweak the above values as you see fit in the range of `[0, 1]`. Feel free to get rid of the parameters you're not interested in tweaking (e.g. since you only have one axis in your figure, you won't care about the `hspace` and `wspace` parameters, which modify the spacing between subplots). These settings can also be modified through the `plt.show()` GUI, but you'd have to do it every time you run the script. A set of good settings for your case is the following:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(top=.83, bottom=.08, left=.08, right=.98)
```

For doing this adjustment automatically, you can try using [`tight_layout()`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html). Add the following line just before `plt.show()`:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

This won't necessarily give the intended results in every case, though.